# jquery popup on load

Tags: jquery, popup, window

i have used fancybox for popup effects.
please see this link
http://www.sudhakargolakaram.co.in/f...ncy/popup.html

here when the link is clicked a popup window appears with the effect created by fancybox

what i need is i want this popup window to appear by default when the page loads

how do i specify that i want this content in a popup window with the effect when the page loads

Comment: without code we really can't help you... even the link you used has no code...

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your code? That link brings up a page with nothing on it, and I'm not familiar with fancbox, but I'd imagine you can do it pretty easily, with something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //execute popup
    });
```

If you say the event is triggered when you click something, you could just use `.trigger("click");`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has an inbuilt function that executes after page load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // call function that is invoked on link click
 });
```

That might help you